# How to pass props into an exported function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
//App.js

import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form'

class App extends React.Component{


render(){

return 

<Form something={true}>

}

}

//Form.js

import React from 'react';
export default class Form extends React.Component{

render(){

return()

}
}

//Index.js
import Form from './Form';
import React from 'react';

export default (props)=>{

<Form {...props} />


}
```

The directory structure:
(Components
->App.js
->(Form -> Form.js, Index.js))

In App.js which component would Form be referring to because im importing from a folder? Both files insider this folder have a default export.
So why is the prop passed into index.js instead of form.js?

Comment: your Index.js file is doing nothing at all.. it's just wrapping a component with another component that does nothing but pass props. is this someone else's code that you are trying to understand or did you write this?

Comment: Its somebody else's code, when im passing in props in App.js into the Form component. Do both files get this props? Since in App.js im importing a Form component from a folder and not a file?

Comment: Since in index,js, im exporting an anonymous function by default when importing i need to give a required name. In App.js does the import of Form refer to this anonymous function or my component in form.js?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea what im talking about ahaha?

Comment: Files don't get props. only components get props. When you pass props in App.js, you're passing the component you export in Index.js, then they get passed to the component loaded from Form.js . @vahissan shouldn't have deleted his answer though, since he is correct that your Index.js component is not returning anything because it's using braces instead of parens

Comment: Why the functional component in Index.js and not the class component in Form.js? Since both are exported by default and the import from App.js is from a folder...?

Comment: if you want it to load the Form and not the index file then change your import statement to `import Form from './Form/Form'`. If the path is a folder then it will load the index file

Comment: Ok understood, thank you